# Can female Claymores give birth to babies for their husbands?

Tags: claymore

I have just finished the Claymore manga. Clare and Raki stay together at the ending of the story. I am sure they are going to get married.

I have a question about the two of them. We know that female Claymores are half-human and half-Yoma hybrid warriors, but in the manga, they never tell us whether female Claymores are able to give birth to babies.

Would Clare be able to get pregnant for Raki?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that Clare would be able to. Since she isn't half yoma, but a third, she has a higher chance of getting pregnant than the average warrior would. In the manga, dragon-kin are probably able to reproduce anyway. That would mean yoma are able to reproduce but probably don't because of lack of necessity.

(Dragon-kin are the beings that the organization used to turn humans into yoma. Yoma, as you know, are the beings used to make the warriors in the organization.)

Honestly, even if she was an average warrior, I think she would. Warriors tend not to have relationships because of the way humans see them and the only men they would encounter are Male awakened beings aside from bandits; as we saw with Teresa. They also have a lot of mental illness and emotional trauma; Ophelia for example as well as Priscilla. They tend to be unemotional or so emotionally unstable that it can be very difficult to form relationships at all.

Let's also not forget that they have a large "wound" running from their neck to their groin and might not be able to even carry one without literally splitting in half. Clare's was momentarily closed when she entered The Destroyer but she had to be practically sewn back together when it appeared again.

So the real problem isn't if she can get pregnant, its if she can carry a baby long term without having real issues.

Answer (score 7):

I think probably not.

**This answer contains manga spoilers (further than the anime)**

In chapter 15, Teresa is ambushed by bandits who wish to rape her. She opens her clothes to reveal something hideous to the men who then back off.

[image]
[image]

Later on we see a body with a large scar down her middle. Presumably this is related to what Teresa has shown the bandits - as she implied that it was a trait shared by claymores.

[image]

[Ref](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=170816#top)

The scars are presumably a mark of their bodies transformation with youma flesh, and being so thorough it wouldn't surprise me if wombs as other normal organs were missing.

At one stage, there is an awakened being that has captured claymores and wants them to awaken - presumably unable to breed its own spawn. As awakened beings are ex-claymores, their anatomy is going to be roughly similar.

Comment: At about the same time as that incision/scar image, it is explained that, while Claymores are quite good at healing and regenerating themselves (some much moreso than others), none of them are able to heal the full-body incision that was made to implant the yoma flesh into them.  So they all walk around with their torso permanently sliced open, with the stitches an attempt to stop their insides from spilling out *en masse*.  Possibly some amount of mucus and the like may seep out regardless, adding to its disgusting appearance.  I cannot clearly recall if wombs were brought up during this.

Answer (score 0):

I noted that when Clare first went to battle an awakened being with Deneve, Miria, and Helen, Helen mentioned how Raki "...Couldn't be one of her own..." in reference to Clare, which can be taken as Clare can't have children, and due to Helen being so sure that the fact of the matter was that Raki wasn't Clare's son, it leads you to believe it is a trait shared among Claymores. However Clare may be a special case due to being only a quarter Yoma, instead of half Yoma.